# How to get the unzipped file directory by using TrueZip

Tags: java, truezip

```
public class unzipAll {

    public static void main(final java.lang.String[] args) throws Exception{
        TFile src = new TFile("C:/1/BULK.tar.gz");
        File dest = new File("C:/Test/");

        dest.mkdirs();

        try {
            src.cp_rp(dest);
            TVFS.umount();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I can use this code to unzip BULK.tar.gz. But I want to know the directory of the unzipped files.

Right now, all the files unzipped to C:/Test/. But it has a sub folder "AAAAA".

I want to get this sub folder name "AAAAA" How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `dest.listFiles()`. It should give you an array of all files and directories in `dest`. There are also versions of `listFiles` that can filter out different kinds of files and/or directories which can be handy at times.

See java api for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html